# Cloning remote repository fails using JGit for http url

Tags: git-clone, jgit

The problem here is, URL is redirected which is not handled in JGit. There are no of bugs reported for same and it is also mentioned that they are resolved but I am still facing this issue. Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

Code Snippet

```java
private static Git cloneRepository(String url, String branch, String targetPath) throws IOException {
    Git result = null;
    try {
        CloneCommand cloneCommand = Git.cloneRepository().setCloneSubmodules(true)
                                        .setURI(url).setBranch(branch)
                                        .setCloneSubmodules(true)
                                        .setDirectory(new File(targetPath));
        result = cloneCommand.call();
    } catch (GitAPIException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    cloneRepository("http://github.com/google/mathfu", "master", "D:/codebase");
    //cloneRepository("https://github.com/google/mathfu", "master", "D:/codebase");
}
```

Exception after running the code

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: 'http://github.com/google/mathfu': 301 Moved Permanently
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:245)
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:293)
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:190)
at com.acellere.demo.GitDemo.App.cloneRepository(App.java:21)
at com.acellere.demo.GitDemo.App.main(App.java:31)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: 'http://github.com/google/mathfu': 301 Moved Permanently
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:545)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch(TransportHttp.java:326)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:136)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:122)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1236)
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:234)
... 4 more
```

After changing following code

---

```
//cloneRepository("http://github.com/google/mathfu", "master", "D:/codebase");
cloneRepository("https://github.com/google/mathfu", "master", "D:/codebase");
```

Exception

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: 'http://github.com/google/fplutil.git': 301 Moved Permanently
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:245)
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:293)
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:190)
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.SubmoduleUpdateCommand.call(SubmoduleUpdateCommand.java:177)
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.cloneSubmodules(CloneCommand.java:372)
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.checkout(CloneCommand.java:353)
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:215)
at com.acellere.demo.GitDemo.App.cloneRepository(App.java:16)
at com.acellere.demo.GitDemo.App.main(App.java:25)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: 'http://github.com/google/fplutil.git': 301 Moved Permanently
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:545)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch(TransportHttp.java:326)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:136)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:122)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1236)
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:234)
... 8 more
```

Details:

using following JGit version
4.8.0.201706111038-r

Also tried with version 4.4.x.xxxxx too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this change: https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/46261/, that was merged in February 2017, JGit should be able to follow HTTP 301 status codes (moved permanently).

However, the `CloneCommand` does not seem to work yet. I can verify that your code snippet throws a `TransportException`.

The corresponding bug reports can be found here:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=465167
  https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=474094

I have added a comment to the bug report that points to this post.

**Update 2017-08-18:** the bug is fixed and will be released in JGit 4.9

Comment: @aoswal my original answer wasn't quite right, please see the updated answer.