# spring-cloud-config server - org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.NoSuchRepositoryException | Cannot clone or checkout repository:?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I'm working with Spring Cloud, and using Config-server to externalize properties for micro-services.

following is the config-server's manifest file

```
server:
  port: 8888

spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/Girdhars/config-server.git
  application:
    name: config-server

management:
  security:
    enabled: false
```

but while accessing the Rest Endpoint http://localhost:8888/application/default
i'm getting below exception.

```
{
    "timestamp": 1515082055134,
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "exception": "org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.NoSuchRepositoryException",
    "message": "Cannot clone or checkout repository: https://github.com/Girdhars/config-server.git",
    "path": "/application/default"
}
```

Comment: remove `.git` from the url?

Comment: @spencergibb , It (.git) really doesn't matter i did remove. but not working

Comment: Are you going through an http proxy? Is that set?

Answer (score 0):

Repository in your configuration points to https://github.com/Girdhars/config-server.git, but after navigating in browser I receive `301 Moved permanently` and I'm redirected to https://github.com/rathore-girdharsingh/config-server.

So I think your issue was related to this redirect. I found [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45200564/9419680) that says :

> With this change: https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/46261/, that was merged in February 2017, JGit should be able to follow HTTP 301 status codes (moved permanently).

Btw, I did a quick check - your configuration is working now with new versions of Spring Cloud (Finchley.RELEASE) and Spring Boot (2.0.3.RELEASE)